# Tell IntelliJ to generate code where fields (member variables) are referenced with `this.` prepended

Tags: java, intellij-idea, this, code-generation, prepend

When IntelliJ 2018.1 generates code for me involving a reference to a class’ [member variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) (field), I want to follow a convention of always prefixing with `this`.

I want:

```
this.firstName = "Lisa" ;
```

…rather than:

```
firstName = "Lisa" ;
```

I tried `Editor` > `Code Style` > `Java` but got an error:

> Not a valid java identifier in prefix 'this.'

[image]

…presumably because this feature is targeting the *definition* of the member variable in the class rather than its *usage* in other code.

➡ Is there someway to make IntelliJ prepend `this.` appropriately when generating code?

By the way, the related issue of a menu command or keyboard shortcut for altering existing code to prepend such member variables with `this.` is discussed in the Question, [*Add this. to member variables/methods in IntelliJ Idea*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19861534/642706).

Comment: Apparently there is a corresponding cleanup action on save. Check some of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861534/add-this-to-member-variables-methods-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Wouldn't you want to prefix the local variable, not the field? In other words, `private String this.name;` is what I am guessing this is trying to create

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't follow your comment. My Question does not involve local variables. I reformatted my example code to hopefully clarify.

Comment: I'm saying that this configuration, for example in Android, would prefix member variables like `private String mFirstName` if you put an `m` there... My point is that I think you are correct when you say it's the declaration of the variable this is setting, not its usage, which would be as a variable within a method, which is what I meant by local variable - its local usage within a method